Spring controller endpoint works unsecured in dev but requires auth on live
I have a Springboot/React app that has a Controller I've set up to accept Webhook messages from a payment provider (Stripe).
@PostMapping(path="webhook")
@ResponseBody
public String webhook(@RequestBody String payload, 
       @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String sigHeader) throws Exception {
...

The URI for the webhook in my local environment is: http://localhost:8081/webhook
Using Postman, I can hit this endpoint without Authentication in my local environment.
However, in my Production environment (Digital Ocean), the request redirects to the login page:
https://recapai.cloud/webhook
Assuming the code is the same in both environments, Are there any gotchas I can check?
I realise there is little detail in this question, but it's all I can provide without specific idea where to look.

Can you add the startup logs for both setups, specifically any mentions of profiles and auth rules? Can you add the SecurityConfig class to the question?
